# I am trying to be back to same screen once I remove the app from the recents but it always takes me back to signup screen even when I have signedIn

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, provider

Unable to get the user back to last screen if looged in and once the app is removed from the background using shared preferences and provider for two separate conatiner's tap and based on that tap user will logged in and a fun which verifies on which profile the user has logged in and will show that particular page once user reopen the app and if logged in only then.

I tried a lot and made a fun within my splashScreen for such thing but not working as expected please look into this.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../Provider/LogicForTappedContainer.dart';

class Onboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Onboard({super.key});

  @override
  State<Onboard> createState() => OnboardState();
}

class OnboardState extends State<Onboard> {
  //check ifLoggedIn state
  Future<void> check(LogicContainer provider)async{
    var sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPref.setBool(OnboardState.KEYLOGIN, false);
    bool? isLoggedIn = sharedPref.getBool(OnboardState.KEYLOGIN);
    var value=provider.tappedContainerIndex;
    print('isLoggedIn: $isLoggedIn');
    print('value: $value');
    if(isLoggedIn==true && value==0){
      context.go('/userMainScreen');
    }
    else if(isLoggedIn==true && value==1){
      context.go('/panditchat');
    }
    else{
      context.go('/signup');
    }
  }
  //shared pref
  static var KEYLOGIN = "login";
  double opacity1 = 0.0;
  double opacity2 = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    whereToGo();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        opacity1 = 1.0;
      });
    });

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      setState(() {
        opacity2 = 1.0;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Consumer<LogicContainer>(builder: (context, provider, child) {
          return Stack(children: [
            Image.asset(
              "assets/logos/Temple.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              height: double.infinity,
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.83,
              left: 80.w,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: opacity1,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    child: Text(
                      "  Welcome",
                      style: GoogleFonts.signikaNegative(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                  AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: opacity2,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    child: Text(
                      "  Worshipper",
                      style: GoogleFonts.signikaNegative(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]);
        }));
  }
  void whereToGo() async {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      LogicContainer myLogicContainer=LogicContainer();
    check(myLogicContainer);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the role of OnboardState.KEYLOGIN? You just put false to that state. It always returns false.

Comment: It is for login and log out track and finally makes you to be back on same page where you were when you were logged in and its initial value is false by default but when logIn it changes to true and again to false when logout.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting your `KEYLOGIN` to `false` always in your `check` function.

In this line

```
 sharedPref.setBool(OnboardState.KEYLOGIN, false);
```

remove the above line from your code it will work fine.

Use this code

```
Future<void> check(LogicContainer provider)async{
var sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool? isLoggedIn = sharedPref.getBool(OnboardState.KEYLOGIN);
var value=provider.tappedContainerIndex;
print('isLoggedIn: $isLoggedIn');
print('value: $value');
if(isLoggedIn==true && value==0){
  context.go('/userMainScreen');
}
else if(isLoggedIn==true && value==1){
  context.go('/panditchat');
}
else{
  context.go('/signup');
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but if I do so then the default value of isLoggedIn becomes true and value has -1 as data. So in this case none of the above case of fun will satisfy and my app will get stuck on splash screen please look if anything else you can do please.